# Angularjs material one row with 2 columns

Tags: angularjs, material-design

i am trying to achieve that, and can't figure how:

> ```
> |-------------80%---------------------|----20%---|
> ```

one row with 2 columns with specific width.

- i don't understand something, columns (usage in Material) are look to me like rows > in rows

> ```
> |-------------------------------------|----//---|
> |-------------------------------------|----//---|
> |-------------------------------------|----//---|
> ```

and not like my example.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you have imported AngularJS and Angular Material (including the css file), you need to import Angular Material in your AngularJS app. To do this, you need to add the "ngMaterial" provider in your AngularJS module, like this:

`var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngMaterial"]);`

(if you skip this part, it won't work).

Then you can write your HTML code as follows

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap>
    <div flex="80">80%</div>
    <div flex="20">20%</div>
</div>
```

This will create a div that will act as a container. It will contain the elements you want to show and they will be aligned in a row and, if necessary, they will be displayed in a second row. In the flex property you can specify the width (as a percentage) of the element compared to the width of the container.

Obviously you can change the name of your Angular module and the number/ width of your html elements as you want.

And there you can see some examples and a bit of [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options)

Comment: Thanks! and what about if i want to add a navigation  to page (up menu), how can i set vertical space as the above? (menu of 20% and the rest as 80%) ?

Comment: @E.Meir You could simply use a Toolbar. It will be placed in top of the screen and if you add to it the css property `position: fixed;` it will remain always at the top, also when you scroll a long page. It will also do all the job for you :) [Here the demos and the documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toolbar)

Comment: Thanks! what about  `<div layout="row" >  <div flex="70" **layout-align="end left"**><div flex="30" **layout-align="center end"**>` how can i set each of the column to be in specific direction?

Comment: @E.Meir If you mean "How to change the alignment?" The answer is easy, simply change the value of the property `layout-align`. The possible values are shown in the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment)

Comment: yes i mean that- so what i wrote in my last comment suppose to work? `layout-align` [roperty suppose to be on a div ?

Comment: tried it now and it didn't work , maybe i do something wrong? i looked here:  [link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment), `<div layout="row" > <div flex="70"  layout-align="start end"> </div>
<div flex="20" layout-align="end end"></div></div>`

Comment: @E.Meir You have to put the property `layout-align` on the container div (the div the `layout="row"` to make it work).

Comment: didn't understand, i should add this `layout-align` to the container div? so in my case `<div layout="row" layout-align >` , like this?

Comment: @E.Meir I've tested it a little. You have many options depending on what your needs are. So if you use the code i posted before, you have to add to the first line (of the HTML code i've posted) this property `layout-align="end end"`. If your child elements are themselves some kind of container and you want to use the `flex` property, you need to add the following line the conteiner opening tag `layout-align="end end"`. If your children elements are themselves containers and you DON'T use the `flex` property, you can add the `layout-align="end end"` on the child opening tag. I hope I helped you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139707/discussion-between-lorenzo-montanari-and-e-meir).

Comment: Thanks- you helped me a lot, if i will have any question 
i will contact you in private (if it possible through here).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to declare:

`md-cols` Number of columns in the grid.

In your case (8+2=10):

`<md-grid-list md-cols="10" ...`

Then your items:

`<md-grid-tile md-colspan="8">...</md-grid-tile>`

`<md-grid-tile md-colspan="2">...</md-grid-tile>`

[Codepen Sample](http://codepen.io/errvald/pen/JWxMGj) - [Angular Material Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdGridList)

Comment: `md-colspan` is a property of grid tile and if i don't use `grid-list` i should use `flex`?